# PackageNotFoundError even though required channel added to anaconda config?

Tags: python, linux, openssl, anaconda, conda

I am working with Ubuntu in WSL and tried to install the required packages for a repo with:

```
$ conda install --file requirements.txt
```

I got a `PackageNotFoundError` for a bunch of different packages. I search on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org) for the required channels and added them. But it doesn't matter which channels I add I always get a `PackageNotFoundError` for the last two remaining packages:

```
$ conda install --file requirements.txt
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - openssl==1.1.1=h7b6447c_0
  - intel-openmp==2019.5=281

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/fastchan/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/fastchan/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cctbx202208/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cctbx202208/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Anaconda.org says `conda-forge, fastchan, cctbx202208` for openssl but even though I added all of them it's still not found.

The next thing I tried was to install it with pip:

```
$ pip install openssl==1.1.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl==1.1.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openssl==1.1.1
```

But pip detects none versions of this package. Same with intel-openmp, but pip does find packages but not the one I want `2019.5`:

```
$ pip install intel-openmp==2019.5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intel-openmp==2019.5 (from versions: 2018.0.0, 2018.0.3, 2019.0, 2020.0.133, 2021.1.1, 2021.1.2, 2021.2.0, 2021.3.0, 2021.4.0, 2022.0.1, 2022.0.2, 2022.1.0, 2022.2.0, 2022.2.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for intel-openmp==2019.5
```

So my question is, is there another way to install the two packages or do they not exists anymore? Because the repo from which I got the code has its last commit from 3 years ago...

**Edit**:

I tried this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda openssl
```

and it installs openssl, but the latest version and than the code still says openssl is missing.

I also tried:

```
conda install -c anaconda openssl=1.1.1
```

but I get the same error as in the beginning (PackageNotFoundError in the channels).

**Edit2**:

[TrackNPred](https://github.com/rohanchandra30/TrackNPred) is the repo I cloned and want to get working.

As for the required channel, I just searched for the package name on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=intel-openmp) and add the channels i see to my anaconda config with:

```
conda config --add channels new_channel
```

I'm not sure if I need the exact version of a package as it's listed in the requirements.txt or if the code also works with another version of the two missing packages.

**Edit3**:

I changed in the `requirements.txt`:

```
openssl=1.1.1*
intel-openmp=2019.5
```

and that worked.

Comment: @merv I edited the question and am currently testing your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Unless you are a reviewer trying to exactly replicate this work, you should be fine with my answer. The exported requirements from these authors are over-specified and you probably only need to match tensorflow version, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require *exact* package build replication, then edit the file to loosen up the specifications.

I see the **intel** channel has `intel-openmp=2019.5=intel_218` and any `openssl=1.1.1` should do. So, find the respective entries in the `requirements.txt` file and edit them to have:

```bash
openssl=1.1.1*
intel-openmp=2019.5
```

then recreate the environment, with **intel** channel added.

```bash
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
conda create -n foo -c defaults -c intel --file requirements.txt
```

Comment: I still get the `PackageNotFoundError` for `openssl==1.1.1`, but `intel-openmp` not anymore so thanks for that.

Comment: @Ghandi try `openssl=1.1` or `openssl=1.1.1*`.

Comment: `openssl=1.1.1*` did the trick, even though anaconda discovered some incompatibilities, but installed some other versions without collisions after that.